# Maximizing minimum of intersection size

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Let $A=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and let $A_1,\dots,A_m$ be subsets of $A$ of the same size.
Let $k$ be a fixed positive integer.
We want to choose $B\subseteq A$ of size $k$ such that $\min(|A_1\cap B|,\dots,|A_m\cap B|)$ is maximized.

Suppose we use a greedy algorithm: First choose an arbitrary set $B$ of size $k$. Then, if there exists an element outside of $B$ that can replace an element in $B$ so that $\min(|A_1\cap B|,\dots,|A_m\cap B|)$ increases, we perform this replacment.

Will this algorithm always terminate at a desired answer, or might it get stuck at a local optimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=\{1,2\}, A_1$ contains $1$ but not $2, A_2$ contains $2$ but not $1$, and all the other $A$s have both $1$ and $2$.  None of the $A$s have $3$ or $4$.  Changing $1$ to $3$ or $2$ to $4$ will not decrease the minimum, but changing both will.

Comment: Do you mean $B=\{3,4\}$ instead of $B=\{1,2\}$? The objective is the maximize the minimum.

Comment: My point is that $B=\{3,4\}$ will have a lower intersection, but you will not find it by the greedy algorithm from $\{1,2\}$.  You have an intersection of $1$ and neither replacing the $1$ nor the $2$ will reduce it.