# Improving set intersection lexicographically

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

> Let $A=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and let $A_1,\dots,A_m$ be subsets of $A$ of the same size.
>   Let $k$ be a fixed positive integer.
>   We want to choose $B\subseteq A$ of size $k$ such that $\min(|A_1\cap B|,\dots,|A_m\cap B|)$ is maximized.

I'm not sure whether a direct approach to find such $B$ exists, so one way is to proceed greedily. First choose an arbitrary set $B$ of size $k$. Then, if possible, we try to "improve" it by replacing an element in $B$ with an element outside it.

If the criterion for improvement is that $\min(|A_1\cap B|,\dots,|A_m\cap B|)$ should increase, we may [get stuck](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631115/maximizing-minimum-of-intersection-size). For example $n=4$, $m=k=2$, $A_1=\{1\}$, $A_2=\{2\}$. Initially $B=\{3,4\}$, and we cannot improve using this criterion. Yet a better $B$ is $B=\{1,2\}$.

So, how about the improvement criterion being that the sequence $(|A_1\cap B|,\dots,|A_m\cap B|)$ improves lexicographically? For sequences $(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_r)$, where we sort $a_1\leq\dots\leq a_r$ and $b_1\leq\dots\leq b_r$, we say that the latter improves the former if, for the first $i$ such that $b_i\neq a_i$, we have $b_i>a_i$. In the example above, we would change $B=\{3,4\}$ to $B=\{1,4\}$, then to $B=\{1,2\}$, resulting in a desired set $B$.

Does this algorithm always end with a desired set $B$, or can it get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me convergence of the proposed algorithm sounds too optimistic and indeed it can get stuck even in the following special case.

Let $G$ be a graph with the set $V$ of vertices. Let $A_1,\dots, A_n$ be edges of $G$ considered as set of size two. If $G$ has a [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of size $k$ then the required minimum is at least one. On the other hand, the algorithm can get stuck  in this case. Indeed, let $V$ be a disjoint union of set $V_1$ and $V_2$ of size four each. Let every vertex of $V_1$ is adjacent to every vertex of $V_2$ and the subgraph of $G$ induced on $V_1$ is a cycle of length four. Then $V_1$ is a vertex-cover of $G$. On the other hand, the algorithm get stuck at a set $V_2$, because it covers all edges of $G$ but four edges of the cycle, whereas each four-element subset $B$ of $V$ with $|B\cap V_2|=3$ covers all but five edges of $G$.

Comment: I don't think it's that trivial. The lexicographic order here is defined so that you compare the smallest element first, not the largest element.

Comment: Lemme check my understanding: The key step is that $B = V_2$ gives the vector $(0,0,0,0,1,1,\dots,1)$ while any $|B \cap V_2| = 3$ gives the vector $(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,\dots,1,2,2,2)$, which is lexicographically worse, right?

Comment: @antkam Yes....

Answer (score 0):

Dualize the problem. Build auxiliary sets $C_1,C_2,.., C_m$ that are subsets of $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ such that $C_i$ contains $j$ if and only if $A_j$ contains $i$.

What happens if we solve the set cover problem with the sets $C_i$? The result is $k$ or less if and only if there is a solution to the original problem in which $\min(|A_1\cap B|,\dots,|A_m\cap B|)$ is at least $1$.

We conclude this problem is at least as hard as the set cover problem. (because moving the $k$ would allow us to solve the set cover problem).

Comment: I don't think it's true that we want to maximize the sum of the $f(a)$. That way we may end up satisfying some sets $A_i$ too much and other sets $A_i$ too little. Note that we want to maximize $\min(|A_1\cap B|,\dots,|A_m\cap B|)$, not $|A_1\cap B|+\dots+|A_m\cap B|$.

Comment: Oh right... I had initiallt solved that version, but then I realized that had nothing to do with lexicographical, let me revert it

Comment: That doesn't answer my question about the proposed algorithm...

Comment: The proposed algorithm is polynomial and thus doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure it's polynomial - the lexicographic order is exponential.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to consider all of the different cases of the relation $|\cap_i A_i|\overset{?}{=} k $. We consider the easier case first as it makes the jump to the 2nd case easier:

> **Case #1** $|\cap_i A_i| \geq k $

**Algorithm for Case #1:**

1. While $|B|<k$

   1.1. Search for any $x \in \cap_i A_i \setminus B$

   1.2. Set $B := B \cup \{x \}$

> **Claim 2** Algorithm #1 is well-defined and optimal.
>
> *(Proof):* The correctness of the algorithm follows from the fact that $|\cap_i A_i| \geq k $ and therefore there always exists some $x \in \cap_i A_i \setminus B$ in line 1.2 of the while loop. It is easy to see that see that $\min \{ |A_i \cap B| \ | \ i \in [m]\}$ is always smaller or equal to $|B|$ and furthermore it is also easy to see that the output of this algorithm gives us $|A_i \cap B| = |B|$ for all $i$; therefore the $B$ is optimal.

The remaining case is more difficult but it contains the crux of the problem:

> **Case #2** $|\cap_i A_i| <  k $

**Algorithm for Case #2:**

1. Set $B := \cap_i A_i$
2. Set $I := [m]$
3. While $|B|<k$

   3.1. Search for the $x \in A \setminus B$ that mixmizes the number of $A_i$ it is contained in, *i.e.* $x$ maximizes $\#|\{ i \in I\ | \ x \in A_i \}|$

   3.2. Set $B := B \cup \{x \}$

   3.3. Set $I := I \setminus \{ i \in [m] \ | \ x \in  A_i \}$

   3.3. If $I == \emptyset$ set $I := [m] \setminus \{ i \in [m] \ | \ |B\cap A_i| > |\min \{ |A_i \cap B| \ | \ i \in [m]\}| \}$

> **Claim 2** Algorithm #2 is well-defined and optimal.
>
> *(Proof):* The correctness of the algorithm is trivial in this case, however the optimaility requires a bit more work. Suppose there were some $C = \{c_1,...,c_k\}$ that gave a better solution than $B = \{b_1,...,b_k\}$; we make a "matrix of labels," $\mathcal{N}^X$, for $X=A,B$ as follows:
>
> **Algorithm #3** to construct matrix $\mathcal{N}^X$
>
> **Input:** $X =  B,C$
>
> 1. Let $\mathcal{N}^X$ be an arbitrarily large matrix of empty strings with potentially varying row lengths
> 2. Set $I = [m]$
> 3. While $X \neq \emptyset $ do
>
>    3.1. search for $Y = \{y_1,...,y_l\} \subset X $ such that $|Y \cap A_i | = |Y \cap A_j |$ for all $i,j \in I $ and $|Y|$ is minimal
>
>    3.2. if such a $Y$ exists then do
>
>    - Set the next empty row of $\mathcal{N}^X$ equal to $(y_1,...,y_l)$, ordered according to the size of $\#|\{ i \in I\ | \ y_j \in A_i \}|$
>    - Set $X : = X \setminus \{y_1,...,y_l\}$
>    - Set $I := I \setminus \{ i \in [m] \ | \ (\exists y \in Y) \ y \in  A_i \}$
>    - If $I == \emptyset$ set $I := [m] \setminus \{ i \in [m] \ | \ |\mathcal{N}^X \cap A_i| > |\min \{ |A_i \cap \mathcal{N}^X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}| \}$ where we consider $\mathcal{N}^X$ as a set
>
>    3.3. else do
>
>    - Set the next empty row of $\mathcal{N}^X$ equal to $(x_1,...,x_l) = X$
>    - Set $X : = \emptyset$
> 4. delete all of the empty rows/labels in $\mathcal{N}^X$
>
> The proof is completed by proving the following lemma:
>
> **Claim 3** The number of rows in $\mathcal{N}^X $ is equal to $\min \{ |A_i \cap X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}  $ or $\min \{ |A_i \cap X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}  + 1$.
>
> *(Proof):*  We prove it by induction on the number of rows. For the base case notice that if Algorithm 3 halted before it created a second row then it *found at most one* set $Y = \{y_1,...,y_l\} \subset X $ such that $|Y \cap A_i | = |Y \cap A_j |$ and was not able to find a second $Y' = \{y_1,...,y_l\} \subset (X \setminus Y)$ that brought the value of $\min \{ |A_i \cap \mathcal{N}^X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}  $ up higher than 1; which proves the base case (because by the end of the algorithm $\mathcal{N}^X = X$ if considered as a set). Assume the induction hypothesis is true if the number of rows of $\mathcal{N}^X$ is equal to $1,...,l$. If we remove the $(l+1)^{th}$ row of $\mathcal{N}^X$ we have that the number of rows in $\mathcal{N}^X _{(1:l)}$ is equal to $\min \{ |A_i \cap (X \setminus \mathcal{N}^X _{l+1})| \ | \ i \in [m]\} +1   $ or $\min \{ |A_i \cap (X \setminus \mathcal{N}^X _{l+1})| \ | \ i \in [m]\}  $ by the induction hypothesis. If the number of rows in $\mathcal{N}^X _{(1:l)}$ is equal to $\min \{ |A_i \cap (X \setminus \mathcal{N}^X _{l+1})| \ | \ i \in [m]\} +1   $ then the last step of the algorithm can at most bring the value of $\min \{ |A_i \cap \mathcal{N}^X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}  $ up by one. Therefore
>
> $ l +1 =  \min \{ |A_i \cap (X \setminus \mathcal{N}^X _{l+1})| \ | \ i \in [m]\} +2  \geq \min \{ |A_i \cap \mathcal{N}^X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}   + 1 = \min \{ |A_i \cap X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}   + 1 $
>
> where the last inequality is at most a difference by 1; as was needed to be shown. If the number of rows in $\mathcal{N}^B _{(1:l)}$ is equal to $\min \{ |A_i \cap (X \setminus \mathcal{N}^X _{l+1})| \ | \ i \in [m]\}   $ then by similar reasoning we have that
>
> $ l +1 =  \min \{ |A_i \cap (X \setminus \mathcal{N}^X _{l+1})| \ | \ i \in [m]\} +1  \leq \min \{ |A_i \cap \mathcal{N}^X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}   + 1 = \min \{ |A_i \cap X| \ | \ i \in [m]\}   + 1 $
>
> where the last inequality is at most a difference by 1; which completes the proof.

Claim 3 completes Claim 2 because it is straight forward to see that the output of Algorithm 2 maximizes the output of Algorithm 3; indeed if $B$ is the output of Algorithm 2 then it is easy to see that $\mathcal{N}^B$ will have the maximum number of rows because Algorithm 2 essentially performs the same steps as Algorithm 3 except that it has all of $A$ to choose from. In particular, we have that

> **Claim 4** If $B$ is the output of Algorithm #2 then $\mathcal{N}^B$ has the maximum number of rows for any set $X$ such that $|X| = |B|$.

*(Proof sketch):* Spelled out explicitly, if $C$ is any other solution we see that at, after possibly reordering $C$, every step where a new row is created in Algorithm 3 the corresponding steps for Algorithm 2 will find the smallest $Y$ that will make $\min \{ |A_i \cap (\mathcal{N}^C \cup Y)| \ | \ i \in [m]\} $ go up by one (if it exists). Therefore Algorithm 2 will always find the optimal "completion" of a set and the proof is completed by a simple induction.

> **Answer to your question about greedy algorithm** Yes a greedy solution works but you must be careful. Your locally optimal choices (or replacements) should either be

1. Search for any $x \in \cap_i A_i \setminus B$

> or when you run out of those

2. Search for the $x \in A \setminus B$ that maximizes the number of $A_i$ it is contained in, for the $i$ such that $ i \notin \{ j \in [m] \ | \ |B\cap A_j| > |\min \{ |A_j \cap B| \ | \ j \in [m]\}| \}$

> as given in algorithms 1 and 2 respectively.